# How to hide file menu in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

How to hide file menu in ubuntu? like Alt in windows is there a shortcut?
**Update:**
Finally got it!
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/nautilus-simple-install-ppa-streamlined.html

Comment: If you fixed it yourself, post the fix as an answer so other users will know how to fix it if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it! http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/nautilus-simple-install-ppa-streamlined.html

Answer (score 0):

It's an open idea: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/10990/.

Comment: finally got it!

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/nautilus-simple-install-ppa-streamlined.html